# Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib 13 (instead of 15)

Tags: macos, octave, dylib

Working with Octave in a Mac with Mountan Lion/Mavericks, when I try to run `hist()` or some other commands, the error message says:

```
Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib requires version 15.0.0 
or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

Where do I get the right library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do the following

```
cd /Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/lib    # move into directory
mv libfreetype.6.dylib libfreetype.6.dylib.bak         # make a backup of current library
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib .               # create a symbolic link to proper library
```

from: http://azaleasays.com/2012/10/20/octave-graphic-error-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have gnuplot.app but I removed libfreetype.6.dylib in folder  /usr/local/lib and replaced it with the symbolic linked and it worked for me. Here's the code: (I have OS X Yosemite)

```
cd /usr/local/lib
rm libfreetype.6.dylib
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib .
```